# AVL Binary Tree: Loneliness Rate

Tags: trees

A node in a binary tree is an only child if it has a parent node, but has no sibling (note that the root is not qualified as an only child). The “loneliness rate” (LR) of a binary tree T is defined as follows:

$$ LR = \frac{\text{number of $T$ nodes that are only children}}{\text{number of $T$ nodes}} $$

Show that for any non-empty AVL tree $T$, $LR(T) \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

---

I'm a little confused... I know that complete or perfect binary trees are AVL. I also know that a perfect binary tree of height $h$ contains $2^{h + 1}-1$ nodes.

But I cannot demonstrate the number of nodes that are only children. Will I have to demonstrate the maximum and minimum number of children?

Comment: I'm a little confused... I know that complete or perfect binary trees are AVL. I also know that a perfect binary tree of height h contains 2 ^ (h + 1) - 1 nodes.

Comment: You should add that to your question. Otherwise it will be closed or deleted.

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: You're welcome I will upvote your question to give it more attention.

Comment: I appreciate it!